# Loop in entity objects and set object's property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity

I have product object. Product object has DiscountRate and Price properties. I want to change price, depending on the discount rate feature. I want to do this for all my Product objects. Here is my code:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        //I want to set change price in here. 
        return _kContext.Products.ToList();
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we can use Foreach method of List. Be aware that original products will be modified:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

_kContext.Products.ToList().ForEach(product => {
    if (product.DiscountRate >= 0.3) {
       product.Price += 10;
    }
});
```

If you don't want your original objects to be modified you can use Linq Select:

```
using System.Linq;
return _kContext.Products.Select(product => {
    var newProduct = new Product();
    newProduct.Price = product.Price;
    newProduct.DiscountRate = product.DiscountRate;
    if (newProduct.DiscountRate >= 0.3) {
       newProduct.Price += 10;
    }
    return newProduct;
});
```

EDIT: Alternative version using property constructors to make more readble.

```
 using System.Linq;
 return _kContext.Products.Select(product => new Product {
        DiscountRate = product.DiscountRate,
        Price = product.Price + ((product.DiscountRate >= 0.3) ? 10 : 0)
 });
```

Comment: Should I include a library to my code for Foreach? Because v.s says cannot resolve symbol Foreach..

Comment: You should cast IEnumerable to IList<T> by calling ToList(). I've fixed the code sample

Comment: Just saw that you wanted to do it inside the method. Made corresponding changes. Please, be aware that your original objects will be modified. If you don't want them to be modified you can use Select(Linq) expression.